# Approximate infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the following sum

$$
I(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n\,e^{-\frac{2n}{\sqrt{x}}} = \frac{e^{2/\sqrt{x}}}{(e^{2/\sqrt{x}}-1)^2}
$$

This is a particular case where I can get a closed form.

However, if I am only interested in an approximation of $I(x)$, I could cut the sum at some finite $n = n_*(x)$, since each term of the series decays exponentially. Then, I would write

$$
I(x) \simeq \sum_{n=0}^{n_*(x)} n\,e^{-\frac{2n}{\sqrt{x}}}
$$

How can I derive an estimate for $n_*(x)$? I know that it must scale as $n_*(x) \sim \sqrt{x}\log(x)$ (checked numerically) but I don't know how to derive it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean as the close form gives a function that can be estimated; what it seems you want is an estimate for some $n$ depending on $x$ and then the estimate depend on the dependence

Comment: @Conrad yes, I want to estimate some $n$ (for each value of $x$) such that I can truncate the sum to get an estimate of the full sum up to some fixed error

Comment: Hint: To estimate the tail of the infinite series $\sum_{n>n_*} ne^{-nt}$, bound it above by $\int_{n_*}^\infty ue^{-ut}\,du$; then set $t=2/\sqrt x$.

Comment: @GregMartin can you give me an extra hint? I am able to bound the tail and I was thinking to require $\int_{n_*}^\infty u e^{-ut} du \ll \int_{0}^{n_*} u e^{-ut} du$.... is that the right thing to do?

Comment: Really, that's a matter of your goal for the calculation, which is something you know much better than I do.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that I properly understood, there is an exact solution to the problem.

You want to know $n_*(x)=m$ such that
$$S_m=\sum_{m+1}^\infty n\,e^{-\frac{2n}{\sqrt{x}}} \leq \epsilon$$ that is to say
$${e^{-\frac{2 m}{\sqrt{x}}} \left((m+1)\,
   e^{\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}}-m\right)} ~\leq ~ \epsilon \,{\left(e^{\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}}-1\right)^2} $$

The solution is given explicitly in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). I let you using the steps given in the linked page but simplifying as much as you can, you could arrive at
$$\color{blue}{n_*(x)= -\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{x}\,\, W_{-1}(-t\,\epsilon)+\coth
   \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)+1\right)}$$ with
$$\color{blue}{t=\frac{4}{\sqrt{x}}\sinh \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)\,\exp\Bigg[-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\coth \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right) \Bigg]}$$

Trying for $x=\pi$ and $\epsilon=10^{-16}$, this would give, as a real, $35.1883$; so $n_*(\pi)=36$.

Checking
$$S_{35}=1.23\times 10^{-16}~ >~ 10^{-16}$$
$$S_{36}=4.09\times 10^{-17}~ <~ 10^{-16}$$

If we look for an asymptotics, we have
$$t=\frac{4  }{e x}\left(1-\frac{1}{6 x}+\frac{11}{360
   x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right) \right)$$

Using the first term only
$$W_{-1}(-t\,\epsilon) \sim \log \left(\frac{4 \epsilon }{e}\right) -\log(x)$$

$$\coth \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)=\sqrt x \left(1+\frac{1}{3 x}-\frac{1}{45 x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right) \right)$$
All of that justify your observation.

**Edit**

Making the problem more general (*this has been my working*)
$$S_m=\sum_{m+1}^\infty n\,e^{-a\,n} \leq \epsilon$$
$$\color{blue}{m=\frac{e^a}{1-e^a}-\frac 1 a W_{-1}(t\,\epsilon)}\qquad \text{where} \qquad \color{blue}{t=a(1-e^a)\,\exp\Bigg[\frac{a\, e^a}{1-e^a} \Bigg]}$$

Expanded as series for small values of $a$
$$m=\left(-\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{a}{12}+O\left(a^3
   \right) \right)-\frac{1}{a}\, W_{-1}\left(-\frac{a^2}{e}\,\epsilon+O\left(a^4\right)\right)$$
$$m\sim -\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{a}\left(1+\log \left(\frac{\epsilon }{e}\right)\right)-\frac 2a \log(a)$$ Using $a=10^{-2}$ and $\epsilon=10^{-16}$; the above gives $4605$ to be compared to the exact value $4998$.

Comment: Hey, this looks exactly what I am looking for. Thanks!! Can you expand a bit on the computations that lead to the blue equations? I don't mean the entire list of steps, but at least the most important ones.

Comment: @apt45. I edited my working. Now, your role is to write the equation in the proper form to be able to use Lambert function using the linked page which gives many examples. Also, on the search bar here, type *Lambert* to see how often it is used (more and more).